# Renormalization of quark bilinears

Tags: operators, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, effective-field-theory

I'm looking at the one-loop corrections to the amputated quark two-point functions ($\Gamma_i$) with insertions of quark bilinears (indexed by $i\in\{S,P,V,A,T\}$) with off-shell legs in Euclidean QCD. I approach the renormalization through an OPE, where the renormalized operators are defined through $O_i^B=Z_{ij}O_j^R$. Since the bilinears are dimension 3 (or $d-1$ in dim. reg.), they should only mix with themselves and $m^3$ through vacuum correlation functions in the case of the scalar. Since the two-point correlation function of $m^3$ is disconnected, I expect that this mixing does not appear in the current calculation. Then, for example, the bare, dimensionally regularized  one-loop correction to the scalar should look like
\begin{equation}
\Gamma_S^B=\Gamma_S^{(0)}\left\{1+g_0^2\frac{C_F}{(4\pi)^2}\left[\frac{A}{\epsilon}+B\right]+\mathcal{O}(g_0^4)\right\}
\end{equation}
for some constants $A$ and $B$ ($B$ includes the logarithms). If I retain all soft scales however, there is an extra term that appears:
\begin{equation}
\Gamma_S^B=\Gamma_S^{(0)}\left\{1+g_0^2\frac{C_F}{(4\pi)^2}\left[\frac{A}{\epsilon}+B\right]+\mathcal{O}(g_0^4)\right\}+C g_0^2\frac{C_F}{(4\pi)^2}\frac{i m_0 p\!\!/}{p^2}.
\end{equation}
This appears to be an off-diagonal mixing with some off-shell operator, but I cannot figure out what this operator could be. Since I'm working in dim. reg., the operator should be dimension 3 as well, but the inverse power of the momentum $p$ makes me nervous. How can an operator like this exist? Initially, I had assumed that my disconnectedness argument above was incorrect and that this was the amputated tree-level of the operator $m^3$, since that would in principle look like $m^3S^{-1}=m^3(i p\!\!/+m)$, where $S$ is the propagator. The new term can be recast as
\begin{equation}
\frac{i m_0 p\!\!/}{p^2}=(\alpha-1)\left(\frac{1}{m_0}S^{-1}-1\right),
\end{equation}
where $\alpha=1+\frac{m_0^2}{p^2}$ is a dimensionless quantity that already appears in $A$, $B$, and $C$. Since $C$ contains no UV poles, and there will therefore be no scale dependence in the residue, this seems safe (there would be a shift in $B$ by $-C(\alpha-1)$). Unfortunately, the $1/m_0$ above is equally unsatisfactory, and moreover this does not even have the desired form for the $m^3$ operator. Further, there is an equivalent structure for each other bilinear, including in particular the parity-odd bilinears which cannot mix with vacuum operators.

I'm not overly worried, since the extra term certainly does not renormalize, so extraction of the $Z$ factors should go smoothly, but I can imagine a situation where the new operator is related to this new term by a quantity proportional to the identity (as in the previous equation), which will shift the finite bit of the correlation function.

In the end, I'm back to asking what the structure $\frac{i m_0 p\!\!/}{p^2}$ could even be. Any ideas? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Defining what it means for operators to mix requires some choice of renormalization scheme, and different schemes can lead to different mixing patterns. As you mention, if you choose some MS-type scheme the only relevant part is the divergent part, which gives no mixing with other types of operators. To treat the term proportional to $C$ as actually mixing, it seems you want a scheme where (for example) the matrix element with $p$ momentum is matched onto the tree-level value. (continued)

Comment: I know that in practice, people sometimes use a similar scheme except they simply require that the trace of the matrix element, or just one of the entries, matches onto the tree-level value, in which case you don't see this spurious mixing (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/9411010 in the context of RI-MOM schemes). It's as if matching the entire dirac matrix onto tree-level requires a much larger basis of operators to solve the equation. I'm certainly still confused though, and I don't understand the full picture.

Comment: That is a good point. I should have clarified that I am using an MS-like subtraction scheme. I want to remain in such a scheme (instead of moving to a MOM scheme, which is not amenable to the larger problem at hand), but you're right; if the $Z$-factors as defined in this post are given as a Laurent series in $\epsilon$, then the scalar density and the spurious contribution do not mix, per se, at one-loop level. (continued)

Comment: However, since the OPE is an operator-level statement, which may be inserted into any amputated correlation funcion, I find it troubling that an extra term appears without reference in the OPE. I would naively say that something about this correlation function moves outside the operator basis which includes the scalar density. I cannot imagine a situation where operators may be constructed with inverse powers of the mass or momenta. There would be an infinite number of operators of each engineering dimension.

Comment: I agree, it is worrying. Actually - I just did the calculation myself and I don't seem to be seeing the same term, I get something like (pslash)/m instead of m(pslash)/p^2, which looks like the operator (psibar dlsash psi), which is a scalar operator of dimension 4; no problems here. Let me check my calculations though

Comment: Actually, I think that is the same term. As I mentioned above, $B$ and $C$ both contain a parameter that I've been calling $\alpha=1+m_0^2/p^2$. The two different structures that we calculate are related by $\frac{i m_0 p\!\!/}{p^2}=(\alpha-1)\frac{i p\!\!/}{m_0}$. This shouldn't be a problem, since there is no pole associated to the spurious contribution in either setting, and therefore no scale dependence in any residue.

Comment: This does have the same problem as the $m^3$ operator I mentioned in the main text though. The $1/m_0$ in the coefficient of the dim-4 fermion kinetic operator is unexpexted, since dim. reg. should be blind to the mixing of operators of different dimensions.

Comment: And if my understanding is correct -- specifically that the operators of higher dimension appear due to the integration of heavy fields out of the path integral -- then there is no way to produce $1/m_0$ terms. My guess is that lower-dimensional ($4>d$) should not be treated the same, since they cannot be constructed in the Wilsonian fashion. They must have coefficients of positive dimension, so they are not "effective" in the same sense. In this case, I should actually look at the mixing of all dim-4 operators with $m_0$*slacar.

Comment: And if my understanding is correct -- specifically that the operators of higher dimension appear due to the integration of heavy fields out of the path integral -- then there is no way to produce $1/_0$
 terms. My guess is that lower-dimensional ($4>$) operators should not be treated the same, since they cannot be constructed in the Wilsonian fashion. They must have coefficients of positive dimension, so they are not "effective" in the same sense. In this case, I should actually look at the mixing of all dim-4 operators with $_0$*scalar.

Answer (score 1):

I think just to clear the air, let's be concrete. Let's calculate the amputated diagram in $d$-dimensions:

[image]

where the $\otimes$ is the $\overline{\psi} \psi$ insertion. The diagram is:

$$i \mathcal{M} = \mu^{4-d} \int \frac{d^d k}{(2 \pi)^d}(i g \gamma^\mu T^a) \frac{i}{ \displaystyle{\not} k \, + \displaystyle{\not} p \, - m} \frac{i}{\displaystyle{\not} k \, + \displaystyle{\not} p \, - m} (i g \gamma_\mu T^a) \frac{-i}{k^2}$$
$$ = -i g^2 \mu^{4-d} C_F \int \frac{d^d k}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{d(k+p)^2 + 2 m (2-d) (\displaystyle{\not} k \, +\displaystyle{\not} p \,) + dm^2 }{k^2 ((k+p)^2 - m^2)^2}$$
The part of interest is the nontrivial $\gamma$-structure part (the middle term in the numerator). We can write this piece as:
$$\begin{split}
i\mathcal{M}_{\mathrm{traceless}} &= -2 (2-d) ig^2 \mu^{4-d} C_F m \int \frac{d^d k}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{\displaystyle{\not} k \, +\displaystyle{\not} p \, }{k^2 ((k+p)^2 - m^2)^2} \\
&= -2 (2-d) ig^2 \mu^{4-d} C_F m \displaystyle{\not} p \, \left( \frac{1}{2 p^2} I(1,1) + \frac{1 + \frac{m^2}{p^2}}{2} I(1,2) - \frac{1}{2 p^2} I(0,2) \right) \\
&= \displaystyle{\not} p \, \left( \frac{C_F \alpha_S}{2 \pi m} + \frac{C_F \alpha_S \epsilon}{4 \pi m}\ln \frac{\tilde{\mu}^2}{m^2} + O(\epsilon^2)\right)
\end{split}$$
In the OPE picture, this seems to correspond to mixing with the dimension-4 operator $\overline{\psi} \displaystyle{\not} \partial \, \psi $, which is allowed due to the presence of the mass scale $m$. At this point, everything seems consistent to me, so maybe I am misunderstanding the question

---

Details:

The master integral is defined:
$$I(m,n) = \int \frac{d^d k}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{1}{(k^2)^m ((k+p)^2 - m^2)^n}$$